# Is it possible to increase partition size in this scenario?

Tags: partition

Output of `fdisk -l` looks like-[image]

I want to increase any one partition from this that will use the free block. I also saw some related Q&A in this site but I am confusing that whether it is possible or not in my case.
How can I do this without data losing?

Comment: My question has a great chance to be duplicated. But, plz vote as duplicate after giving yes/no answer(possible/not possible). Then refer to a duplicate question. Thanks.

Comment: You can increase the /dev/sda4. After that you can extend /dev/sda6. Provided you are careful, you won't lose any data should you follow the process I mentioned above.

Comment: @GMaster, can you give a example?

Comment: I see https://codesilence.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/live-resizing-of-an-ext4-filesytem-on-linux/. but how can I know my free space block from where I can create or resize partition?